# Why can't I pass self as a named argument to an instance method in Python?

Tags: python, methods, language-lawyer, metaprogramming, python-2.x

This works:

```
>>> def bar(x, y):
...     print x, y
...
>>> bar(y=3, x=1)
1 3
```

And this works:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def bar(self, x, y):
...             print x, y
...
>>> z = Foo()
>>> z.bar(y=3, x=1)
1 3
```

And even this works:

```
>>> Foo.bar(z, y=3, x=1)
1 3
```

But why doesn't this work in Python 2.x?

```
>>> Foo.bar(self=z, y=3, x=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method bar() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

This makes metaprogramming more difficult, because it requires special case handling. I'm curious if it's somehow necessary by Python's semantics or just an artifact of implementation.

Comment: Class names should be capitalized, i.e., `class Foo(object)`.

Answer (score 6):

`z.bar` is a *bound* method -- it already has an `im_self` attribute that becomes the first argument (conventionally named `self`) to the underlying function object, the bound method's `im_func` attribute.  To override that you obviously need to re-bind `im_self` (**edit**: or call the `im_func` instead) -- whatever you do in terms of argument passing is not going to have any effect on it, of course.  Yep, that's **the** documented way bound methods object work in Python (not just an implementation detail: every correct Python implementation has to do it exactly this way).  So it's "necessary" in the sense that it's part of what makes Python exactly the language it is, as opposed to being a slighty or strongly different language.  Of course you could design a different language that chooses to play by completely different rules, but -- it wouldn't be Python, of course.

**Edit**: the OP's edits clarified he's calling an *unbound* method, not a bound one.  This still doesn't work, and the reason is clear from the error message the attempt gets:

> TypeError: unbound method bar() must
>   be called with Foo instance as first
>   argument (got nothing instead)

The rule underlying this very clear error message is that the instance must be **the first argument** (so of course a positional one: named arguments have no ordering).  The unbound method doesn't "know" (nor care) what that parameter's *name* may be (and the use of name `self` for it is only a *convention*, **not** a rule of the Python language): it only care about the unambiguous condition of "first argument" (among the positional ones, of course).

This obscure corner case could certainly be altered (with a Python 3.2 patch, if and when the language-changes "freeze" ends;-) by making unbound methods seriously more complicated: they'd have to introspect and save the first-argument's name at creation time, and check keyword arguments on each call just in case somebody's passing `self` by name instead of by position.  I don't think this would break any existing, working code, it would only slow down just about every existing Python program.  If you write and propose a patch implementing this complication, and get active on python-dev to advocate for it against the sure-to-come firestorm of opposition, you do no doubt stand a > 0 chance to ram it through -- good luck.

The rest of us, meanwhile, will keep getting the `im_func` attribute instead, as one absurdly-tiny extra step in what has to be a pretty complicated inded edifice of metaprogramming to warrant such a change -- it isn't a "special case" at all, compared with the horrid difficulties of adapting named-argument passing to **builtins** that don't *take* named arguments (and don't expose their "argument names" to easily allow the transformation of named arguments into positional ones (now *that* would be a windmill worth attacking, IMHO: of all callables, builtins are the worst to metaprogram about, because of that!-).

Comment: `foo` is the class, so `foo.bar` is an unbound method, no?

Comment: As I understand the term, foo.bar is not a bound method, because foo is a class, not an instance. foo.bar has an im_self attribute, but its value is None.

Comment: @Mike: `z.bar()` *isn't* being called; `Foo.bar()` is. The question is why not specifying a kwarg for self works, while specifying it fails.

Comment: Alex, I'm not sure I understand your edited answer, specifically the part about a performance penalty. Currently if you call a function with named arguments, python has no choice but to inspect the original function's definition to determine the parameter names. I don't understand why 'self' would have any extra performance burden compared to any other parameter. kwargs would only need to be searched for 'self' if self wasn't already passed positionally (like any other parameter) or via normal object.method invocation. It's likely I don't appreciate how this interacts with all python features.

Comment: @Joseph, right now the bound-method object's `__call__` peels the first positional argument off, typechecks it, and hands all other work to the underlying `im_func` -- it doesn't even **look** at named args (the underlying func of course does, just like every other function always must -- except pesky builtin ones which don't *take* named args).  Having unbound methods' `__call__` "know" the name of the first argument and check for it is the extra work.  Do the patch to Python's runtime that I suggested, and time it to see if it slows things down, by how much, and exactly how.

Comment: @Alex: I couldn't help attacking your windmill, how does this look?: http://pastebin.com/pUcZPFsV

Comment: @Joseph, _slow_ -- that's how it looks, and there's the rub... builtins are fast to call and frequently called.  BTW, if you're OK with requiring a transformation before named parms can be passed then your problem as posed in this Question totally and immediately disappears of course -- the needed transformation for THAT is so incredibly simpler, just use the `im_func` attribute of the unbound method object rather than the object itself -- it's actually even faster as it *saves* the normal unbound method overhead!-)

Comment: @Alex: If you want to see my misguided metaprogramming goal, it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448187/

Comment: @Alex: I'm not sure I buy your claim that "it would only slow down just about every existing Python program" -- looking at instancemethod_call() in Objects/classobject.c, it looks to me like you could make the necessary change without any effect on the main code path.  That said, I still agree with you that it's probably not worth doing. :)

Comment: Note that there is *nothing to patch for Python 3.2* (or any later Python 3 version) as unbound methods have gone the (deserved) way of the Dodo in Python 3. There is no unbound method anymore, instead the unwrapped original function object is returned and you can use keyword arguments for the `self` parameter to your hearts content.